# schtasks to load outlook on startup

Tags: microsoft-outlook

My work will not let us have outlook start on startup and have the startup folder password protected.  We can create schtasks commands to start it, but I can't seem to get it to work properly.  Any help with a task to start Outlook on startup, with every startup?

Comment: Can you describe what the values you have for the triggers and actions in the task scheduler?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You might mention to management that both methods end the same and using the Startup capacity is less work overall. and therefore more productive

Answer (score 0):

Are you meeting startup Outlook issue? Can you provide us more useful information to analyze your problem?

If you are suffering the hang on startup issue,the case on Microsoft Q&A forum can give you some inspiration:[enter link description here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/766684/outlook-hangs-on-startup)
It is recommended firstly try to create a new profile(Control Panel>Mail>Show Profiles>add) and add other types of accounts in Outlook, such as Gmail account, and to check whether the outlook client can work normally.
It also maybe caused by your register,you also can try to rename your Outlook register key(Location: Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook, rename it to Outlook1), then restart your Outlook to check whether the problems still persist.